# sudo apt dist-upgrade fails

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

On Ubuntu desktop 22.04.

Running dist-upgrade produces:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libwacom2 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libcanberra-pulse but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libwacom2 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: gir1.2-mutter-6 (>= 3.36.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmutter-6-0 (>= 3.36.0) but it is not going to be installed
 mutter : Depends: libmutter-6-0 (>= 3.29.4) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.8-venv (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans
                  Recommends: libreoffice-pdfimport but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-style-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: thunderbird but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: thunderbird-gnome-support but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal : Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Tried manually installing all unmet dependencies, but turns out all of them have already been installed (albeit at different version numbers).

Tried running apt install with --reinstall flag on "depends" packages, got:

```
einstallation of gir1.2-mutter-6 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of gvfs-bin is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of libmutter-6-0 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of libwacom2 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 146 not upgraded.
```

Question: what commands can I run to troubleshoot why these things cannot be downloaded? I have checked internet connection and everything, things seem fine.

Maybe related:
The following PPA can't be updated due to a 401 unauthorized error... is this what's causing the downloads to fail?
`deb https://packagecloud.io/screen/screen/debian/ buster main` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/screen.list`

I tried commenting and uncommenting that `deb https` line in screen.list. Manual reinstall of the missing dependencies still doesn't work, and dist-upgrade returns the same error. What in the holy hell is going on?

Also note:

- Have tried `sudo apt -f install`, `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`

All of them run fine. `dist-upgrade` still does not work.

May be relevant: i recently removed all libreoffice-* packages (sudo apt remove or something).

UPDATE:

For additional context, I originally installed Ubuntu 18.04 around 2019, then did an upgrade to 22.04 about 1 year back since I haven't used my ubuntu for a while. As part of the upgrade, I vaguely remember the installer telling me it was going to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 first, then 22.04. Perhaps that's why some of my sources.list.d contains commented out sources that reference focal, with comments saying it was disabled due to the upgrade to 22.04.

Output of lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Output of apt policy gir1.2-mutter-6:

```
gir1.2-mutter-6:
  Installed: 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of apt policy libreoffice-calc:

```
libreoffice-calc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3
  Version table:
     4:7.5.5-0ubuntu0.23.04.1~bpo22.04.1 100
        100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Running sudo apt update gives:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [101 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [288 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,924 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [15.5 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [43.0 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.0 kB]
Fetched 830 kB in 5s (163 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
146 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

If I go and then run sudo apt upgrade, it gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 python2.7-minimal vlc-data libvlccore9 vlc imagemagick
  libavcodec-extra vlc-bin vlc-l10n libopenexr25 libpostproc55
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra vlc-plugin-samba libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  libavcodec-extra58 libpython2.7 vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56
  imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 python2.7-dev libpython2.7-dev
  python2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libvlc-bin libpython2.7-stdlib
  vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  duplicity eog evolution-data-server gcc-10-base gdb gdm3 gedit gedit-common gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gjs gnome-calendar gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  gnome-startup-applications gsettings-desktop-schemas gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs hplip hplip-data
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-perl libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1
  libextutils-depends-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libgdm1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl
  libgweather-3-16 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libinput-bin libinput10 libldb2 liblocale-gettext-perl libnautilus-extension1a libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnma0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib librhythmbox-core10 libsane libsane-common
  libsane-hpaio libsemanage-common libsmbclient libsocket6-perl libsub-name-perl libtalloc2 libtevent0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwbclient0 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-parser-perl mutter nautilus nautilus-data network-manager-gnome ntfs-3g
  passwd perl perl-base perl-openssl-defaults printer-driver-hpcups python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend
  python3-cups python3-dbus python3-dev python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-markupsafe
  python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-pil python3-protobuf python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-systemd
  python3-talloc python3-venv python3-yaml qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret
  remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins samba-libs sane-utils transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ubuntu-session ubuntu-settings update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny
  xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xserver-xorg-input-libinput yaru-theme-gnome-shell
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 146 not upgraded.
```

Running `apt-mark showhold` gives no output. Neither does running `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold.`

UPDATE 2:

I tried running the following to check if there is anything installed under that weird Debian PPA, thankfully nothing seems to be installed from there:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all installed packages
packages=$(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}')

for package in $packages; do
    # Check the installation source of the package
    result=$(apt-cache policy $package | grep "https://packagecloud.io/screen/screen/debian/")
    if [ ! -z "$result" ]; then
        echo "$package is from https://packagecloud.io/screen/screen/debian/"
    fi
done
```

Above code produces no output.

For additional context, this is my `sources.list.d`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 166 Nov 15  2022 bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 166 Nov 15  2022 bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134 Nov 15  2022 bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164 Nov 15  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164 Nov 15  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Nov 15  2022 deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179 Aug 22 00:37 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 216 Nov 15  2022 erlang-solutions.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 216 Nov 15  2022 erlang-solutions.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184 Nov 15  2022 erlang-solutions.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 267 Aug 22 00:24 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222 Nov 15  2022 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189 Nov 15  2022 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Nov 15  2022 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Nov 15  2022 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144 Nov 15  2022 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 Aug 22 00:36 redis.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 295 Aug 22 01:21 screen.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 216 Nov 15  2022 screen.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 183 Nov 15  2022 screen.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158 Nov 15  2022 tj-ubuntu-bugfixes-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158 Nov 15  2022 tj-ubuntu-bugfixes-bionic.list.distUpgrade
```

I saw the following sources have been automatically commented out due to the upgrade to focal:

```
bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-bionic.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
erlang-solutions.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
tj-ubuntu-bugfixes-bionic.list
```

`redis`, `docker`, `chrome`, and `screen` have been manually commented out for now.

*I am a linux noob so apologies for any dumb mistakes :( Trying to google/ask chatgpt for every terminal output to understand the concepts behind it.

Comment: Why in the world do you have a Debian buster ppa in your Ubuntu sources list? I predict an interesting problem resolution here. Consider examining your sources lists to see what other antics you've been up to. If you have other lines in there that don't say ubuntu jammy...

Comment: Hi guys, I've updated the question with more details. I also wanna say thank you so much in advance for helping and asking questions, I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Another interesting problem: `gir1.2-mutter-6` is a dependency of `gnome-shell` ONLY in Ubuntu 20.04. Not Ubuntu 22.04 (it's not in 22.04 at all). That suggests your release-upgrade to 22.04 failed or partially-failed. Several possible reasons for such failure. All those PPAs and other non-Ubuntu software are among the most common reason, so suspicious.